# If make_heap is slowing down a path planning program, are there solutions or alternatives to solve it?

Tags: c++, priority-queue, heap

**Quick version of the issue:**

I've worked with a D* Lite path planner in C++ but it takes a lot longer than I hoped when it encounters an obstacle. During a test on a 2560x2560 map I discovered that re-planning around an obstacle that appears at the start takes approximately 49.5 seconds, but 42.8 seconds of that is spent in the function that inserts new nodes into the heap, a function that looks like this:

```
void DstarPlanner::insertHeap(unsigned int id, HeapKey k) {
  U.push_back({ k, id });
  make_heap(U.begin(), U.end(), KeyCompare());
}
```

The keys and other variables used in the function are as such:

```
using Cost = float;
using Edge = pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>;
using HeapKey = pair<Cost, Cost>;
using KeyCompare = std::greater<std::pair<HeapKey, unsigned int>>;
vector<pair<HeapKey, unsigned int>> U;
```

Basically I'm wondering if there's some solution to this I can implement to get those faster times D* Lite is supposed to have? Some quick line of code, or other function that solves everything is always a nice fantasy, but ready to try whatever, I just don't have time to rebuild the entire program. So if make_heap is as fast as it gets, well, I guess I'll just run with that.

**More details regarding the issue:**

I've studied the issue a bit and apparently the 'time complexity of insertion in heap' is a thing. My tests shows that D* Lite replanning is faster than making a new plan with my program, however, I dusted off an old A* planner I made and while it can't do a map of similar size, it is faster than my D* Lite on smaller maps when an obstacle appear at [1][1]. When the obstacle disappears my D* Lite is faster than A*, but I had hoped it would be faster in both cases.

My A* uses cells in an openlist defined by:

```
struct cells {
  int currentCell;
  float fCost;
};

multiset<cells> OPL;
```

Instead of a heap. I found an D* Lite program online that used:

```
ds_pq openList;
```

Where ds_pq is defined as:

```
typedef std::priority_queue<state, std::vector<state>, std::greater<state>> dq_pq
```

But whether this is better or faster I don't know as I haven't been able to run the program.

Comment: Use `std::push_heap` instead? It's designed for this pattern of adding at the back, and works off of the heap invariant

Comment: [`std::push_heap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/push_heap) seems more appropriate than rebuild heap...

Comment: `std::push_heap` does make a huge difference it seems. Thank you ^^

Comment: make heap is O(N) which is great for turning completely unsorted data into a heap. However, because you already have a heap, adding an element should be O(log N), which push_heap does. It only worries about how to put the new item into the existing heap. And of course you're inserting multiple times so we're talking n^2 vs n log n